# VB 6.0 Run-time error '3709': The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context

Tags: vb6

I'm coding BASIC in VB 6.0. I'm creating a database and there is this one problem I have. This Save button of mine. When I run it and click on the Save button it says

> "Run-time error '3709':The connection cannot be used to perform this
>   operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context"

**This is my code on the Save Button**

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
rs.Open "SELECT *FROM Table1 WHERE FirstName = '" & Text1.Text & "' AND LastName = '" & Text2.Text & "'", db
If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
MsgBox "RECORD EXISTS"
Else
If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
rs.Open "SELECT *FROM Table1", rs
rs.AddNew
rs!FirstName = Text1.Text
rs!LastName = Text2.Text
rs.Update
MsgBox "SAVED"
Text1.Text = ""
Text2.Text = ""
End If
End Sub
```

**And this is my code in the Module**

```
Dim Text1, Text2 As String
Public db As New ADODB.Connection
Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Public Sub Main()
Set db = New ADODB.Connection
db.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; " & " Data Source = " & App.Path & "\Database1.mdb"
db.Open
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
Form3.Show
End Sub
```

**And this is the Highlighted code**

```vb
rs.Open "SELECT *FROM Table1 WHERE FirstName = '" & Text1.Text & "' AND LastName = '" & Text2.Text & "'", db
```

Comment: It does not like the db connection.  Break on rs.open and inspect db to see if it is actually open.  Other than that the code looks ok to me.

Comment: adUseClient is read only. So you should use adUseServer

Answer (score 0):

Make your project startup object is Sub Main in project properties.

Goto Project Menu->(Your Project Name) Properties. In General Tab, change startup object to Sub Main.